# How to prevent duplications when generating strings from context free grammar

Tags: python, context-free-grammar, formal-languages, automata-theory

I need to define context free grammar and generate strings from this language.

Grammar for a language that contains all strings with matched parentheses:

```
s->ss
s->(s)
s->()
```

Examples: `(), ()(), (()),…`

For generating strings I use usual [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Root is `s`. Production rules are the edges. Each terminal node is a string.

Problem: At some point there exist node: `sss`. From this node there exists 3 different edges to get the same node `ssss`:

```
[s->ss]ss = s[s->ss]s=ss[s->ss]
```

What is the right approach to prune duplication edges?

1. Disambiguate the grammar. How to do it for this language?
2. Change generating procedure (BFS)?

Code:

```
from collections import deque

# rules
rules1 = [('s', 'ss'), 
         ('s', '(s)'),
          ('s', '()')]

# tree
def get_edges(node, rules):
  edges = []
  for count, item in enumerate(node):
    for rule in rules:
      if item == rule[0]:
        edges.append((count, rule[1], rule[0]))

  return edges

def get_nodes(node, edges, rules):
  nodes = map(lambda edge: node[:edge[0]] + edge[1] + node[edge[0]+len(edge[2]):], edges)
  
  return list(nodes)

def get_adjacent_nodes(node, rules):
  edges = get_edges(node, rules)
  nodes = get_nodes(node, edges, rules) 

  return nodes

# search
def BFS_simple(G, root, goal, max_nodes_visited=10 ** 4):
  Q = deque()
  explored = set()

  explored.add(root)
  Q.append(root)

  log_total_nodes_visited = 0
  log_number_of_duplications = 0

  while len(Q) > 0:
    v = Q.popleft()

    if v == goal:
      print('total nodes visited = ', log_total_nodes_visited, 'duplications = ', log_number_of_duplications)
      return v

    for node in G(v):
      if node not in explored:
        explored.add(node)
        Q.append(node)

      else:
        log_number_of_duplications += 1

    log_total_nodes_visited += 1
    if log_total_nodes_visited > max_nodes_visited:
      return False

  return False

BFS_simple(lambda node: get_adjacent_nodes(node, rules1), 's', '(()()())')
```

Result: `total nodes visited =  1244 duplications =  6527`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia entry on BFS says: (emphasis added)

> Breadth-first search can be generalized to graphs, when the start node (sometimes referred to as a 'search key') is explicitly given, and **precautions are taken against following a vertex twice**.

and the pseudocode implementation includes such a precaution (see lines 10 and 11 reproduced below):

> ```
>   9  for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
>   10   if w is not labeled as explored then
>   11     label w as explored
>   12     Q.enqueue(w)
> ```

It does not mention how to "label w as explored"; two common strategies are to use an additional data structure which maps nodes to a Boolean (either a dictionary or an array, depending on how nodes are identified) or to augment the node data structure with an additional Boolean field.

That will work for any grammar, but it is not necessary fo unambiguous grammars. Since it is trivial to find an unambiguous grammar for a [Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language), you could save some time by using it instead of rejecting duplicate results. But I would suggest writing the graph-oriented BFS any way, because the overhead is slight and it allows a wider range of possible grammars.

Comment: I have implemented: "label w as explored". If the language is ambiguous then search algorithm will not explore already explored nodes but it will check if this node was explored: "if w is not labeled as explored". In ambiguous case the number of already explored nodes far more than not explored (in my post: 1244 vs 6527). It looks like Disambiguate grammar is the only way.

Comment: @Oleg: Sure, disambiguating the grammar is a lot more efficient, and highly recommended. And it's not hard to find an unambiguous grammar for Dyck languages.

Comment: I thought there is possibility to implement more effective search procedure with ambiguous grammar. My real grammar is much more complex. It will not be easy to disambiguate.

Comment: @oleg: you could certainly do that search more efficiently, assuming your grammar is context-free. Even with an unambiguous grammar, I think the search graph you construct will visit the same sentential form multiple times because you are not restricting the enumeration to leftmost derivations.

Comment: Verified. I tried it with an unambiguous grammar and it still produces duplicates, as expected.

Comment: did you use: `rules2 = [('s', '(s)s'), ('s', '(s)'), ('s', '()s'),('s', '()')]` ?

Comment: Can you please sketch effective algorithm to produce less duplicates? Extension to BFS? Or maybe there is a name for such algorithm so I can read more and implement it.

Comment: @oleg: basically that grammar but with the productions in the other order, which only affects the search order.

Comment: Instead of treating every possible substitution as an edge, just use the possible substitutions for the *first* non-terminal in the sentential form ("node"). It's still a BFS, though; the difference is that the graph being searched over is a tree instead of a DAG

Comment: Also, I don't see any good reason to eliminate ε-productions; the search algorithm is not affected afaics.

Comment: after adding ε-productions: ('s', '') the number of duplications increased

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) I have made 2 improvements and it dramatically increased search speed:

1. Disambiguate the grammar and correct order: `[('s', '()'), ('s', '()s'), ('s', '(s)'), ('s', '(s)s')]`
2. Instead of treating every possible substitution as an edge, just use the possible substitutions for the first non-terminal node ([left most derivation](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/tag/leftmost-derivation-and-rightmost-derivation/)).

Following code is just extension to the code from my post to show solution. (it is possible to skip filtering and generate edges only for left most non-terminal node)

```
def get_leftmost_non_terminal(edges):
  if len(edges) == 0:
    return edges
  return filter(lambda edge: edge[0] == edges[0][0], edges)


def get_adjacent_nodes(node, rules):
  edges = get_edges(node, rules)
  left_most = get_leftmost_non_terminal(edges)
  nodes = get_nodes(node, left_most, rules) 
  
  return nodes
```

Performance tests:

```
s = '(()(())())'

BFS_simple(lambda node: get_adjacent_nodes(node, rules1), 's', s)
#total nodes visited =  656 duplications =  188

BFS_simple(lambda node: get_adjacent_nodes(node, rules_unambiguous_empty), 's', s)
#total nodes visited =  537 duplications =  490

BFS_simple(lambda node: get_adjacent_nodes(node, rules_unambiguous), 's', s)
#total nodes visited =  536 duplications =  0

BFS_simple(lambda node: get_adjacent_nodes(node, rules_unambiguous_ordered), 's', s)
#total nodes visited =  361 duplications =  0
```

Comment: The unambiguous empty grammar is `[('s', ''), ('s', '(s)s')]` (or the other order). If you add `s->ε` to the unambiguous grammar, it becomes ambiguous, which is why there are duplications. The unambiguous grammar with an empty production does generate more nodes before finding the target (656 or 828, depending on order), basically because it doesn't generate nodes in order by length, so it produces some longer nodes before hitting the target. But if you're using this technique to see if a target string is recognised, you should really reconsider. Parsers are much faster.

Comment: I use this technique for program synthesis. I have a grammar for program space and use DFS for search: program that fulfils dataset of (input, output)